# How can I see upvotes and downvotes for documentation article?

Tags: support, documentation, vote-count

For any question or answer at SO I can see not only summary vote but numbers of upvotes and downvotes:

[image]

I know I need to get some reputation for it. So I already did it.
**But can I see the same picture for documentation articles?**
Is it impossible or I just need more reputation for it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Update: Feb 5

This seems to be available in Documentation now.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

That functionality doesn't exist in docs.